# How can I calculate date with different date format in SAS EG

Tags: sql, sas

I'm doing a SAS EG question which is asking for the year, orginal data `Employee_Hire_Date` provided in the table is formatted like `01JAN1960`, I'm trying using `(01/01/2012 - date)/365.25` and the result returned seems to be an wrong answer. What should I do?

```
proc sql;
/* Question 1 */
select Employee_ID, Salary format=dollar12.2, (Employee_Hire_Date - 01/01/2012)/365.25 'Duration(Year)' format=number6.2
    from employee_information
    where Job_Title = 'Sales Rep. I'
    having Employee_Hire_Date > 31/12/1979 and Employee_Term_Date = .
    order by Salary desc;
quit;
```

Comment: One divided by one divided by 2,012 is not a date.  Did you mean `'01JAN2012'd` ?

Comment: Does EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE have date values? What is the TYPE of the variable?  What format (if any) is attached to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide dates as a [date literal in SAS](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_017/proccas/p14t12jhqk5yzmn11oewj4c1ehh2.htm), which means like '01Jan2022'd.

```
proc sql;
/* Question 1 */
select Employee_ID, Salary format=dollar12.2, (Employee_Hire_Date - '01Jan2012'd)/365.25 'Duration(Year)' format=number6.2
    from employee_information
    where Job_Title = 'Sales Rep. I'
    having Employee_Hire_Date > '31Dec1979'd and Employee_Term_Date = .
    order by Salary desc;
quit;
```

I would recommend looking into [INTCK](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.11/lefunctionsref/p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm#:%7E:text=Returns%20the%20number%20of%20interval,%2C%20times%2C%20or%20datetime%20values.) as well if you're looking to calculate differences in dates rather than just using plain math.